# Using privet SSH key without a file

Tags: shell, terminal

I usually would do `ssh -i PrivetKeyFileName localhost`, but this time, I only have the key, and I do not have write permission to save the key to a file and use it like shown.
is it possible to pass the key as an argument? (or any other solution really)

Comment: You are a user of the system, so probably with a home (maybe not in standard locations), you may still have few `tmp` directories (but you should asses the risk). But probably `sudo` is the right tool (either instead of ssh, or to execute ssh with specific key)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, you should try to include more information to get yourself better answers.  Like it doesn't make sense what you are trying to accomplish or why - so you should probably stick to best practices and setup your machine to use multiple ssh keys in the `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: Sorry for your pain, but StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su] or possibly [unix.se] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below command but it is only effective to a single runtime command on the remote machine.

```
echo $PrivateKEY | ssh -i /dev/stdin username@hostname command
```

Due to sensitive information in the key it is not recommended to use it in as a string. Try creating a file with correct permission and use it.